# BabylonJS Execute Script from External File

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I'm having a (simple) issue, but I have no idea how to fix it. Essentially, every tutorial I have come across for Babylon puts all of the Javascript code inside < script > tags in the main HTML page. 
However, I would like to have all of my Javascript code inside a separate file. I have tried every way of loading it as I could think of, though I am a novice at Javascript (I am decent at C++, and I can see the similarities); yet I was unable to make it load. (It works fine when called from the HTML page itself).

Does anyone know what (if anything) I can do in order to be able to load my scripts from external files, and still get everything to work? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

- register to the DOMContentLoaded event in your external JS file
- reference your JS file with the  tag at the end of the HTML page

  You can find a sample in one of my tutorials here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2014/11/18/understanding-collisions-amp-physics-by-building-a-cool-webgl-babylon-js-demo-with-oimo-js.aspx

Enjoy and thanks for using Babylon.js! :)

David

Comment: I actually found that page earlier today, after doing a bit more research on my issue. Thus far, I have opted to simply ignore the issue, but I'll look into it further. 

Is there any reason why the DOMContentLoaded event won't load if the file is loaded locally?

Furthermore, do you have any suggestions towards handling input without cameras? I saw your video on the Babylon Docs about input, but it was mostly about different camera types. I'd like to be able to move around an object in the scene, independent of the camera; I've just been following a tutorial so far, but its for Babylon 1.3 :/

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using Cordova and Ionic as well. I'm starting to wonder if the problem isn't something else, since I've copied code from Microsoft and other (reliable) sources, and yet, it still isn't working. 

I don't suppose anyone might have any ideas? This is very frustrating.